# How to use substring and indexOf for a String with repeating characters?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I have the following `String myString="city(Denver) AND state(Colorado)";`
It has repeating "(" and ")"...

How can I retrieve state name, i.e. Colorado. I tried the following:

```
String state = myString.substring(myString.indexOf("state(")+1,myString.indexOf(")"));
```

But it give `indexOutOfBoundException`

Is there any way to specify that I need the second "(" in myString?
I need the result: `String state = "Colorado";`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf`. Also increase the initial offset to allow for the number of characters in the sub-string `state(`:

```
String state = myString.substring(myString.indexOf("state(") + 6, myString.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Comment: Thanks it works! May i ask just in case I have this `"("` repeating multiple times, e.g. `myString="abc(defg(h(i(k(o"`. Is there any way to specify that I need the third `"("`? Can I use: `myString.thirdIndexOf("("))`...probably not?

Comment: In that case you would use [indexOf(String, startIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) Of course you would have to the location of the 3rd ( by getting the indices from substrings again using `indexOf(String, startIndex)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Regex.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(state)(\(.*?\))").matcher(text);
String state = matcher.group(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just cut the string down, and do it in a sanboxed piece. This way if there are more trailing ")" nothing bad happens

```
String state = myString.substring(myString.indexOf("state(")+6);
state = state.substring(0,state.indexOf(")"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use other version of [String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to specify from what position you would like to start searching `")"`.

```
int start = myString.indexOf("state(")+6;//6 is the length of "state(" - we dont want that part
int end = myString.indexOf(")", start);
String state = myString.substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the first occurrence of `")"` is before the occurrence of `"state("`, as it also appears after `Denver`.

If you need the last index, you could use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29), for both `"("` and `")"`. If you need precisely the second occurrence, you could use the [version of `indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) that lets you specify an index where to start the search, and set that index to be the one after the first occurrence of your char, Like this:

```
 int firstOpenP = myString.indexOf("(");
 int firstClosedP = myString.indexOf(")");
 int secondOpenP = myString.indexOf("(", firstOpenP + 1);
 int secondClosedP = myString.indexOf(")", firstClosedP + 1);
 String state = myString.substring(secondOpenP + 1, secondClosedP);
```