# Substring of a string java

Tags: java, string, substring

Below is a String and I want to get the bold id from it.

```
String s = "> Index1 is: 261 String is: href: <a href="https://www.clover.com/v3/merchants/4B8BF3Y5NJH7P/orders/K0AH5696MRG6J?access_token=4ffcfacefd3b2e9611a448da68fff91f">https://www.clover.com/v3/merchants/4B8BF3Y5NJH7P/orders/K0AH5696MRG6J?access_token=4ffcfacefd3b2e9611a448da68fff91f</a>, id: **K0AH5696MRG6J**, currency: USD, title: Greta , note:  This is test ,"；
int ind = s.indexOf("id:");
s = s.substring(ind,s.indexOf(","));
```

It gives an error index out of bound.

I know that error is there because in substring(int,int) the second parameter value is not correct.

I am trying to get the substring between `id:` and `,`.

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
s.indexOf(",", ind)
```

to get the comma which is after the `id:` rather than the first one in the String.

If you haven't read all the methods in String yet, I suggest you do as you will be using this class again, and again.

Comment: @user1486269 I don't know how many years I used Java before I read the Javadocs for `java.lang` and `java.util` end to end and wished I had done it sooner.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because [`substring` found that end index was less than the begin index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

> Throws:
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Your initial `indexOf` call finds the `id:` properly, but the call to `s.indexOf(",")` finds the first `,` in the string, which happens to be before `id:`.

Use an [overload of `indexOf` that takes a second argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) - the index at which to starting looking.

```
s = s.substring(ind,s.indexOf(",", ind));
```

Answer (score 0):

your "," index is before your "id:" index. You must search , after id

```
// Search id:
int ind = s.indexOf("id:");

// After that: search comma
int comma = s.indexOf(",", ind +1);
```

this explains this sort of problems:

[How to use substring and indexOf for a String with repeating characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764314/how-to-use-substring-and-indexof-for-a-string-with-repeating-characters)

Comment: How should I search after ID?